# What is the section of Javascript ? - wwOpenInstalled

Tags: javascript, web

Ok so I start coding websites (yes I know I am almost 15 years late :0) and in many of the sites I see the following javascript:

```
<script language="javascript"><!--

var wwOpenInstalled;
if (wwOpenInstalled || parent.wwOpenInstalled) {
    if (window.Event) {
        document.captureEvents (Event.MOUSEUP);
    }
    document.onmouseup = (parent.wwOpenInstalled) ? parent.wwOnMouseUp : wwOnMouseUp;
}
//--></script>
```

This is a very simple question. Why is it here and what does it do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use WebWasher, or McAfee Web Protection? That looks like code inserted by webWasher to trap links and protect against viruses or trojans.

Comment: I am in a corporate office. You think WebWasher is injecting this ?

Answer (score 0):

By doing a [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=parent+wwOpenInstalled+MOUSEUP) on some of the keywords of the code, seems that this code is injected from a script of StatCounter, a service to track and get statistics of the visitors on your page.

But by reading the code, seems that is pretty outdated, the [captureEvents](http://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/window.captureEvents) function is now obsolete.

For website traffic analysis I highly recommend you [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

Comment: If you read those pages, you'll see that it had nothing to do with statcounter... Someone complained to the statcounter folks, blaming them, that's all. http://forum.statcounter.com/vb/archive/index.php/t-18076.html